# urdf beginner error

Tags: ros, urdf, urdf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the first tutorial, for 'creating a urdf file'. On part 2 on creating the tree structure. I saved the xml as advised. Then 'rosmake urdf_parser' it compiles without any errors. Then after when i run the 'rosrun urdf_parser check_urdf my_urdf.xml' line.

the following error occurs :

Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file

ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed

If anyone has any ideas for what i could do, i would very grateful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12858/urdf-beginner-error/) by [Patrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/1729/patrick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2012-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you both for your help, ive updated my ubuntu and using a different text editor and the error does not appear.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/1729/patrick/) with karma: 40 on 2012-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like your XML-file causes an error... is it the same one as in the tutorial?

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had a similar problem like yours. I just gave the whole path of the file instead of just the file name and it worked fine.

---

Originally posted by [Prashant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2710/prashant/) with karma: 31 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2014-03-12**:
thanks, it works